# loop iteration doesnt work like it should

Tags: c#, mysql, loops, iteration

Everything works fine except the `labels[i]`. The loop is always writing in htmlLabel1 and never in htmlLabel2 etc. 
Why does the iteration doesn't work by `labels[i]` but at `Reader.GetValue(i)` just fine?

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT number FROM numbers ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2; ";
MySqlDataReader Reader;
connection.Open();
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (Reader.Read())
{
    HtmlLabel[] labels = new HtmlLabel[] {
        htmlLabel1,
        htmlLabel2,
        htmlLabel3
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        labels[i].Text = Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(Reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
    }
}
connection.Close();
```

Comment: You are retrieving one column for each record. The inner loop loops only one time for each record

Comment: @Florian The for loop on Reader.FieldCount is looping through the columns in your select statement on Line 3.  There is only one field, number, to loop through.  What are you trying to loop through?

Comment: @LAS I though its the best way. I wanna get 10 rnd entrys from mysql and paste every entry into a different label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one field so Reader.FieldCount will return 1 every time.
if you want to loop through rows use the following code

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT number FROM numbers ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2; ";
MySqlDataReader Reader;
connection.Open();
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
int i=0;
HtmlLabel[] labels = new HtmlLabel[] {
    htmlLabel1,
    htmlLabel2,
    htmlLabel3
};
while (Reader.Read())
{

    //for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
    //{
        labels[i].Text = Reader[0].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(Reader[0].ToString());
    //}
    i +=1;
}
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code with no explanation - that doesn't help anybody.

Comment: @Fatehi_Alqadasi Thanks but now i get IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: It's depend on length of labels array

Comment: @Fatehi_Alqadasi Thank you. After i copied your version in my visual studio it works perfect.